# Rocket.chat File Upload

Tags: linux, centos, rocket.chat

File upload does not work with GridFS in CentOS; file uploads get stuck at 0%.

I changed it to FileSystem and now it works after restarting the service.

Where exactly do the files reside once uploaded?

Side question: anyone know why GridFS does not work?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well. GridFS worked for a few days then stopped. It turns out GridFS is using a subdirectory in /var/tmp which was getting automatically deleted. If you switch to FileSystem you can manually specify the upload location in the server admin configuration.